# Ignite Partition Loss Immediately After Cache Creation

Tags: ignite

I am using ignite 2.8.1 in a 4 node cluster with persistence enabled. I was attempting to do a rolling restart of the cluster but I believe during that process the cluster ended up having partition loss seemingly all on one node in the cluster. I am using policy READ_ONLY_SAFE. From that point on, even though all the nodes came back up, about every 1 in 8 times I would create a cache it would immediately have partition loss in the new cache, i.e. we would create the cache and then query it 1 second later and the queries would fail with "Failed to execute query because cache partition has been lost". How can partitions be lost immediately after creation if no cluster event has happened such as nodes leaving the cluster?

Comment: Please show your current baseline topology (control.sh can do that)

Comment: Could you please share a configuration of the cache where you're getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

Partitions for newly created caches may be lost if cluster has some nodes absent from baseline / in "lost partition" state.

This is so that affinity collocation would work. Since on 2 caches with same affinity configurations partitions need to be collocated by node, there's nowhere to put these "extra" partitions for newly created caches.

You need to reset lost partitions first.